# What is the best practice for servers - EFI or legacy mode?

Tags: linux, bios, uefi, boot-loader

I'm currently installing a new Linux server and am trying to decide whether to use legacy mode (BIOS) or EFI. So far, I'm leaning towards legacy because it's less complex (less partitions) and has been working well so far for all our other machines. Moreover the Supermicro implementation [doesn't seem to be particularly issue-free](https://github.com/rhboot/efibootmgr/issues/19#issuecomment-595516274).

I'm very reluctant to use anything legacy on a new machine, but with EFI I haven't really been able to find a sufficient reason to use EFI so far. My main concern with legacy boot (BIOS) is whether I can expect it to be generally supported in the future.

So - is it advisable to use legacy boot in 2023?

Comment: Is your boot disk larger than 2TB? If so, you'll most likely need EFI boot - though, not necessarily. It's worth noting that grub creates a small BIOS boot partition in the case of a large drive anyway, so, you're not reducing the number of partitions anyway - of course, if you are using `Supermicro` then avoid the issue and use legacy